# how doctrine entityRepository works?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

i'm new on doctrine orm so i try to learn some tutorial on

```
ps:knpuniversity.com/screencast/doctrine-queries/dql
```

but i still confused  for exp:

```
src/AppBundle/Entity/Category.php

class Category
{

    private $id;

    private $name;

    private $iconKey;

    private $fortuneCookies;
```

We  can access build in method by

```
$categoryRepository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Category');
        $categories = $categoryRepository->findAll();
```

But if we want to access new method we can do this

```
$categoryRepository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Category');
        $categories = $categoryRepository->findAllOrdered();
```

Then provide class for repository

src/AppBundle/Entity/CategoryRepository.php

```
class CategoryRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllOrdered()
    {
        die('this query will blow your mind...');
    }
}
```

**i still not get it!!**

```
$categoryRepository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Category');
```

if those above point to category entity, how come it suddenly can link to `CategoryRepository` and we could access  `findAllOrdered()` method?

did i missed something guys please help?

Comment: You are missing the part where the category entity is linked to your custom category repository.  @AlbertoFecchi - Wrong and misleading.  The repository prefix has nothing to do with anything. https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html

Comment: thanks @Cerad now i understand the logic /**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductCategory")
 */
class Category

Answer (score 1):

As several developers told you, it's important to link your Entity class with your Repository class through the annotations.

- `@ORM\Table(name="your_entity_name")`
- `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Your_RepositoryClass")`

If you want to call your `repository` with a name more customized (e.g. '`repository.category`' instead of '`AppBundle:Category`'), you can create a service through a yml file.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you are using annotations and most probably you have an annotation of the entity class. You just have to specify the repository class like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\CategoryRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="Category")
 */
```

Specify